# Let $R,S$ be rings, $\phi: R\ \to S$ is a homomorphism, I is an ideal of R , J is an ideal of S. Prove $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of R.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R,S$ be rings, $\phi: R\ \to S$ is a homomorphism, I is an ideal of R , J is an ideal of S.

Prove $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of R.

I read [Proving that an inverse ring homomorphism of an ideal is an ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989648/proving-that-an-inverse-ring-homomorphism-of-an-ideal-is-an-ideal)

In Kavi Rama Murthy comment , I don't understand why he showed that $i_1+i_2 \in \phi^{-1} (J)$.

My attempt :

I have to show that $ri\in \phi^{-1}(J),\forall r\in R, i\in \phi^{-1}(J)$

$\phi(ri)=\phi(r)\phi(i)\underset{\phi(r)\in S, \phi(i)\in J}{\implies} \phi(ri)\in J\implies ri\in \phi^{-1}(J)$

I have some problems :

1. Is it correct that $\phi(i) \in J$ , in another words , in case $I$ is an ideal $\phi(I)$ is ideal as well ?
2. If 1 is not correct what about the case that $r\notin I$ and $\phi(r)\in J$ , IS it possible ?

Thanks !

Thanks !

Comment: if $\phi$ is surjective, then $\phi (I)$ is an ideal

Comment: To show $\phi ^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal, you need to check one more condition: $a,b\in \phi ^{-1}(J)\Longrightarrow a-b\in \phi ^{-1}(J)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideal $\ I\ $ seems to me to be a red herring. If $\ r\in R\ $ and $\ i\in\phi^{-1}(J)\ $, then $\ \phi(i)\in J\ $.  Therefore $\ \phi(r)\phi(i)\in J\ $, because $\ J\ $ is an ideal of $\ S\ $.  But since $\ \phi\ $ is a homomorphism $\ \phi(ri)=$$\,\phi(r)\phi(i)\in$$\, J\ $, and hence $\ ri\in\phi^{-1}(J)\ $.

As Lozenges points out in a comment, you also have to show that $\ a-b\in\phi^{-1}(J)\  $ for any $\ a,b\in\phi^{-1}(J)\ $.  Are you able to do that?